# How to make dissolve animation on changing views on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation

How to make dissolve animation on changing views in iphone?

Dissolve effect: one view is changing another without any movement.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The animation you're looking for is:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                 animations:^{
                     view1.alpha = 0.0;
                     view2.alpha = 1.0;
                 }];
```

A more complete solution, using that animation might be:

```
- (void) replaceView: (UIView *) currentView withView: (UIView *) newView
{
    newView.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview: newView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                     animations:^{
                         currentView.alpha = 0.0;
                         newView.alpha = 1.0;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [currentView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use [UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) in ios5 and later...

```
[UIView transitionFromView:currentView
                    toView:nextView
                  duration:2
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
                    }];
```

Comment: Thanks! Deployment to iOS 4.3 will no be available with this code?

Comment: ya I already told in this... It will be used for ios5 and later :)

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` has a method called [`transition(from:to:duration:options:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622562-transition) that has the following declaration:

```
class func transition(from fromView: UIView, to toView: UIView, duration: TimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [], completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

> Creates a transition animation between the specified views using the given parameters.

---

Among the many `UIViewAnimationOptions` parameters that you can pass to  `transition(from:to:duration:options:completion:)` is [`transitionCrossDissolve`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622499-transitioncrossdissolve).

`transitionCrossDissolve` has the following declaration:

```
static var transitionCrossDissolve: UIViewAnimationOptions { get }
```

> A transition that dissolves from one view to the next.

---

The following Swift 3 Playground code shows how to toggle between two `UIViews` with a cross dissolve transition by using `transition(from:to:duration:options:completion:)` and `transitionCrossDissolve`:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let firstView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    let secondView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(firstView)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func toggle(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let presentedView = view.subviews.first === firstView ? firstView : secondView
        let presentingView = view.subviews.first !== firstView ? firstView : secondView        
        UIView.transition(from: presentedView, to: presentingView, duration: 1, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: nil)
    }

}

let controller = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"cross dissolve" context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0f];
self.firstView.alpha = 0.0f;
self.secondView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I think it's better not to use this methods. Blocks are far more elegant. As Apple documentation says: Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later.

Comment: block-based programming. See the answer by @Ashley Mills.