# implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationOption to different enumeration type uiviewanimation transition

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

This is my code for giving a crossdissolve effect for an image

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    typedef enum
    {
        UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve,
        UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown,
        UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp,
        UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom,
        UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
} UIViewAnimationOptions;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void){

    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve forView:img cache: YES];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(void){
            [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve forView:img cache: YES];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];
    }];
}
```

But i am getting a warning **implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationOption to different enumeration type uiviewanimation transition.**

But if i give **UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp .....** it is working,but animatewithoptions is giving warning.

can anyone help me?

Comment: and actually i need the reverse of cross dissolve effect.can anyone help me in this too?

Comment: why are you typedef-ing the UIViewAnimationOptions enum?

Comment: Removing typedef will solve your issue.

Comment: @wattson12 i add typedef inorder to remove that warning

Comment: the warning is there for a reason, it was telling you something is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You are using the enum of `UIViewAnimationOption`.

The enum defined for `UIViewAnimationTransition` is:

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

Please check [UIView Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for reference.

Also remove the enum defined by you, there is no need of it. The iOS already have the enum for `UIView` class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to typedef the animation options enum, its already been done

The error is telling you what is wrong, you are passing in a type `UIViewAnimationOption` when the method expects a `UIViewAnimationTransition`

the valid options for animation transition are:

```
typedef enum {    
    UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,    
    UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,   
    UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,    
    UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,    
    UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown, 
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

Comment: But there is no dissolving effect in this category.How to get that dissolving effect

Comment: the dissolving effect is an animation option, so you need to do an animation with that set as an option. its not one of the default transitions you can access. You should be using the transitionToView: method, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546262/1138900